# How can I execute this in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm a beginner to MySQL. I'm trying to execute this in MySQL. I want to omit all the PARENTIDs where PROPERTYVALUE='NG'. 
My Input is like this:

[image]

My Output should be like this:

[image]

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: add code to SO not links + images

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE PARENTID NOT IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT(PARENTID) FROM table_name WHERE PROPERTYVALUE = "NG"
)
```